# Does XMPP supports history?

Tags: google-talk, xmpp

Does XMPP protocol itself support message history?

I mean, when I go offline, can I retrieve messages I would have recieved if I were online?

I'm using GTalk with XMPP client and I can't see history of chat when I were offline, I have to go into a GMail a see them here... I don't know if it is lack of XMPP protocol, XMPP client, or just GTalk doesn't support this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the server implementation, I'd assume actively maintained/developed projects do, e.g. prosody, tigase, mongoose.im

Useful links:

- Flexible offline message retrieval http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0013.html
- Best Practices for Handling Offline Messages http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0160.html
- Delayed delivery http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0203.html
- [Can XMPP/Jabber support editing of messages and offline message like in Skype?](https://superuser.com/questions/463112/can-xmpp-jabber-support-editing-of-messages-and-offline-message-like-in-skype)

Answer (score 1):

From the *Google Talk* documentation ["Offline friend can't receive messages"](https://support.google.com/talk/answer/52654?hl=en):

When you can’t receive message while being offline, check the following:

1. Your *Google Talk* username needs to be associated with a *Google* account that uses *Google Mail*.
2. The [chat history](https://support.google.com/talk/answer/161925?hl=en) needs to be enabled in your *Google Mail* account.

Or when it only happens from time to time or only for specific contacts:

- The sender was "chatting off the record" when you went offline.